# reclaim the space after a large delete in oracle

Tags: oracle

In my application we are uploaded huge data.if any wrongly uploaded data then we can delete the data.So,whatever data deleted that space when will reclaim the data?.is there any impact on performance Is there anyway to reclaim the space after a large delete in oracle?.How to reclaim the space?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934037/shrink-a-database-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Oracle, deleting data does not automatically reclaim disk space. The database will retain its storage until you do *something* administrative to the tablespace. The expectation of this behavior is that if you needed the storage at one time, you will likely need it again and it would therefore be more efficient to simply keep the allocation.

As far as performance impact, less data to process will generally make queries go faster. :)

To reclaim the space, you have a few choices. [This article from ORACLE-BASE](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ReclaimingUnusedSpace.php) has a pretty comprehensive look at this situation.

Also, why would you insert data, then determine it is "bad" to then delete it? Wouldn't you be better off avoiding putting the data in from the beginning?

Comment: This is a major problem in our development environment which forces us to create a new database every 6-8 months and drop the old one.  We add anywhere from 10-15 new users per night for testing / development purposes and drop the old ones after a week.  The problem with the table space reclamation is that if any piece of data resides in the tablespace towards the end of the file - you can't reclaim any of the free space in the middle.  It's quite annoying actually.

Comment: If you're constantly dropping/creating users and have a lot of weird useage patterns, then why not give each user their own tablespace?

Comment: That is one option - and after looking at this latest build I did give the "auto" users their own tablespace - so I can delete them and drop the tablespace and not have to drop the db.  I'm not sure I want to do the tablespace per user - but agree it is a viable option.  Thanks for the input.....!!!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563408/shrink-permanent-tablespace-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 3):

You need to research the [High Water Mark](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=599313) (HWM).

Basically it is the maximum number of blocks that has ever been used by a specific table, if you load a large volume of data them you may well increase the HWM, deleting those records does not then reduce the HWM.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131024092101/https://sysdba.wordpress.com/2006/04/28/how-to-adjust-the-high-watermark-in-oracle-10g-alter-table-shrink/) is a great article on how to adjust the HWM and if, once you understand it, you think it may be affecting your environment then use the tips included to reduce your HWM.

Hope it helps...

Comment: The link to sysdba.wordpress.com is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reclaim space after delete. but if after the delete the size of the remaining data is relatively small then create a new table with the data, drop the old table and rename the new table to the old name

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but for future references:

- DELETE empty the table but space is already "locked" for future fillings
- TRUNCATE TABLE do the trick (you need to disable all foreign keys referencing the table in order to work).