# Best way to shrink database of oracle

Tags: oracle

Need help to shrink database of oracle just like MSSQL. I am not so familiar with oracle database.

Comment: This might help: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schema003.htm#ADMIN11601 and check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934037

Answer (score 1):

To shrink the database, you can use ALTER TABLE, ALTER INDEX, ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW, or ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG statement with the SHRINK SPACE clause.

`SQL> alter table testTable enable row movement;`

`Table altered`

`SQL> alter table testTable shrink space;`

`Table altered`